# How to correct styling in a horizontal 2 level superfish menu

Tags: css, superfish

I have a horizontal superfish menu with two levels. When I hover over a first level link, the second level drop down appears approx 2ems lower than the bottom of top level links although firebug says the style is:

```
.sf-menu li:hover > ul, .sf-menu li.sfHover > ul {
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0em;
}
```

No matter how much I try to raise the bottom  position (eg. bottom: -2.5em), the second level menu will not raise up. This leads me to think that the browser (Firefox) may be forcing a gap, but I cannot find evidence of that.

How can I override this incorrect positioning or find out what might be the cause?

Answer (score 3):

Can you post a link to your site?

Its a bit tricky to answer specifically.... but as a guess try targeting:

`.sf-menu ul a {`

This is some good , clearly coloured css to help you, it can be tricky to get to grips with superfish css...

**Theme skin:**

```
/*** COLOR SKIN ***/

/* main ul element */
.sf-menu {
    border-right: 1px solid FUCHSIA;
    float:left;
}

/* general link styles*/
.sf-menu a {
    display: block;
    padding:9px 13px;
    text-decoration:none;
    border-top: 1px solid;
    border-left: 1px solid;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
}

/*** 1st Level ***/

/* 1st level links, no hover, no visits */
.sf-menu li a {
    color: yellow;
    background-color: green;
    border-color: red;
}
/* 1st level links, while hovering over sub menu */
.sf-menu li.sfHover a{
    color: black;
    background-color: silver;
}

/* 1st level links, hover */
.sf-menu li a:hover {
    color: white;
    background-color: lime;
}

/* 1st level current page */
.sf-menu .current_page_item a,
.sf-menu .current_page_ancestor a,
.sf-menu .current_page_parent a {
    border-bottom-color: white;
    background-color: TEAL;
}

/* 1st level down triangles with pure css*/
.sf-menu li .sf-sub-indicator {
    text-indent:-9999px;
    line-height: 0;
    border-color:YELLOW transparent transparent;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:4px; /*controls size of triangle */
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:5px;
}

/*** 2nd level ***/

/* sub menu */
.sf-menu ul {
    border-right:1px solid;
    border-bottom:1px solid;
    border-color: yellow;
}
.sf-menu li:hover ul,
.sf-menu li.sfHover ul {
    top:32px; /* overriding essential styles- adjust if you have gaps between first level and drop-down sub menu*/
}
.sf-menu ul ul {
    margin-top:0; /*unlikely to need adjusting */
}

/* 2nd level links, no hover */
.sf-menu li li a, .sf-menu li.sfHover li a {
    color: orange;
    background-color: blue;
    border-color: green;
    border-bottom: 0;
}

/* 2nd level links, while hovering over sub menu */
.sf-menu li li.sfHover a{
    color: black;
    background-color: silver;
}

/* 2nd level links, hover */
.sf-menu li li a:hover, .sf-menu li.sfHover li a:hover {
    color: white;
    background-color: aqua;
}

/* 2nd level current page */
.sf-menu li li.current_page_item a,
.sf-menu li li.current_page_ancestor a,
.sf-menu li li.current_page_parent a {
    background-color: TEAL;
}

/* 2nd level side triangles with pure CSS */
.sf-menu li li .sf-sub-indicator { /*right arrow*/
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent WHITE;
}

/*** 3rd Level and beyond ***/

/* 3rd level links, no hover */
.sf-menu li li li a, .sf-menu li.sfHover li li a {
    color: blue;
    background-color: red;
    border-color: blue;
}

/* 3rd level links, hover */
.sf-menu li li li a:hover, .sf-menu li.sfHover li li a:hover {
    color: white;
    background-color: pink;
}

/* 2nd level current page */
.sf-menu li li li.current_page_item a,
.sf-menu li li li.current_page_ancestor a,
.sf-menu li li li.current_page_parent a {
    background-color: TEAL;
}
```